# How to use the prop allowsInlineMediaPlayback in react-native-WKWebView?

Tags: ios, react-native, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'm using WKWebview in ios for my react native project. My project requirement is to disable the vidoe taking a full screen by default. This could be done in UIWebView by setting the the prop allowsInlineMediaPlayback to true but WKWebview does not support this prop. Is there any other way I can set this prop to in order to disable the video taking full screen in my Webview?

```
<WKWebView
source={{
uri: "videocheck/02_1.2_Objectives_in_financial_management.html"
}}
ref={webView => (this.webView = webView)}
originWhitelist={'["*"]'}
javaScriptEnabled={true}
domStorageEnabled={true}
startInLoadingState={true}
useWebKit={true}
//scalesPageToFit={true}
scrollEnabled={false}
// onLoad={() => this.sendPostMessage()}
allowFileAccess={true}
allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}
/>
```